# conting correct answer saving to highscore

Tags: android, save, settext

im creating a quiz that has 3 questions/levels. my problem is i dont know what to implement or to code on how to count the correct answer. like for example the user click the right answer(button) it will count and add until he reaches level3. and after he finishes the game my complete.class will pop up and has a button that if the user click highscore(button) it will automatically set text to my highscore.class

levelone.class

```
public class EasyOne extends Activity {

ImageButton a, b, c;
Intent intent ;
CountDownTimer cdt;
TextView timer;
MediaPlayer player;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.easyone);
    a = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_a);
    b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_b);
    c = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_c);
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_timer);
    cdt = new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               timer.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
              timer.setText("TIMES UP!");
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TimesUp.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    };

    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChoiceTwo.class);
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);


            cdt.cancel();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChoiceTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });


    cdt.start();
}
}
```

complete.class
    public class complete extends Activity  {

```
Button highscore;
String highestScore;
int score;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
highscore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
highscore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override   
       public void onClick(View v) {

       SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
       if (score > preferences.getInt("score", 0)) {
            preferences.edit().putInt("score", score).commit();
       }
       Intent showHighScore = new Intent(MainActivity.this, highscore.class);
       showHighScore.putExtra("current_score", score);
       startActivity(showHighScore);
    }
});
}
}
```

highscore.class

```
public class highscore extends Activity {
Button back;
TextView highScore;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highscore);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int currentScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("current_score", 0);
    highScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_highscore);
    highScore.setText(currentScore + " / " + preferences.getInt("score", 0));
    int highestScore = -1;
//Now use this score variable to set anywhere.
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
         highestScore = extras.getInt("score");
        }


    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override   
       public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Back",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
 });    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a static variable for your high_score `public static int HIGH_SCORE` and increase it every time the user answer correctly. Show it when the game finishes.

Comment: In the `Complete` class create a static variable `public static int HIGH_SCORE`. In your `EasyOne` class, every time the user answer correctly, just increase the static variable by Complete.HIGH_SCORE++; . And show it when the game finish.Hope it helps

Comment: @Roberto Lombardini There are many ways to do, that is the fastest way (of course it is NOT recommended) and due to the situation we have here, only one game happens at the time so static variable maybe the appropriate choice.

Comment: @user2652394 get it, but i think a simple class var would do the work

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for tracking score like this:

```
    public class HudScore {

        private int score;

        public HudScore(){
            score = 0;
        }

        public void reset(){
            score = 0;
        }

        public int getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        public void addPoints() {
            this.score +=50 ;
        }

    }
```

Then create an instance of this class in your activity :

```
public static final HudScore score = new HudScore();
```

You can also write a textView for showing score in your layout:

```
Tectview scoreView;
```

for every right answer you can call :

```
score.addPoints();
```

and write a refreshscore() function to update the scoreview textView:

```
    public void refreshScore(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
        @Override
        public void run() {
            YourActivity.scoreView.setText("SCORE: "+score.getScore());
        }
        });
    }
```

Now for Highscore create another class for it like this :

```
    public class Highscore {

        private SharedPreferences preferences;
        private String names[];
        private long score[];

        public Highscore(Context context) {
            preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Highscore", 0);
            names = new String[10];
            score = new long[10];
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                names[x] = preferences.getString("name" + x, "-");
                score[x] = preferences.getLong("score" + x, 0);
            }
        }

        public String getName(int x) {
            // get the name of the x-th position in the Highscore-List
            return names[x];
        }

        public long getScore(int x) {
            // get the score of the x-th position in the Highscore-List
            return score[x];
        }

        public boolean inHighscore(long score) {
            // test, if the score is in the Highscore-List
            int position;
            for (position = 0; position < 10 && this.score[position] >= score; position++)
                ;
            if (position == 10)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        public boolean addScore(String name, long score) {
            // add the score with the name to the Highscore-List
            int position;
            for (position = 0; position < 10 && this.score[position] > score; position++);

            if (position == 10)
                return false;
            for (int x = 9; x > position; x--) {
                names[x] = names[x - 1];
                this.score[x] = this.score[x - 1];
            }

            this.names[position] = new String(name);
            this.score[position] = score;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                editor.putString("name" + x, this.names[x]);
                editor.putLong("score" + x, this.score[x]);
            }
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now in your main activiy create an instance of HighScore class and trigger an alertdialog when the user crosses high score like this:

```
final Highscore highscore = new Highscore(getApplicationContext());

if(highscore.inHighscore(score.getScore()))
{
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this);

        alert.setTitle("HIGHSCORE");
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.trophy);
        alert.setMessage("Score : "+score.getScore()+"\nEnter your name:");

        final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(GameActivity.this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(GameActivity.this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        input.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        layout.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
        layout.addView(input);

        alert.setView(layout);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          String value = input.getText().toString();

            highscore.addScore(value,score.getScore());
          finish();
          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
              finish();
          }
        });

        alert.show();
    }
});


Hope this answers your question.
```

Comment: waaaaaaaa hahahah! so many codes can you help me edit my work

Comment: I just picked the code from my place. for your concern you can just make a variabe in your Score class and update from your activity. And once it reaches high score, show a dialog to user. If he presses Ok, save the score to sharedPreferences so that you can refer it later also. Hope now it sounds simple.

Comment: You just need to see HudScore and HighScore class in my code. Use them in your code

Comment: so hard :( im newbie android dev hahaha

Comment: which part of code you did not understand? put two classes HudScore and HighScore in your application. Then I have showd you how to use them in your MainActivity. Just have a patient look at it. Its really simple. you dont have to use all the code..

Comment: i dont know where to put public static final HudScore score = new HudScore();//which activity? and also this one Tectview scoreView;
for every right answer you can call :

score.addPoints();
and write a refreshscore() function to update the scoreview textView:

    public void refreshScore(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
        @Override
        public void run() {
            YourActivity.scoreView.setText("SCORE: "+score.getScore());
        }
        });
    }

Comment: I think your each level is new activity. So you need to call HudScore score = new HudScore(); in all three level activities. At the end of each level, write the score to sharedPreference. And at the start of next level, read that sharedPreference and update Hudscore and then start calling addPoints again..

Comment: im a newbie so it so difficult for me to undertand hahahaha.sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

By just using static variable, it wont retain the highscore value once the application exits. You also need to save the value to SharePreference.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this code:

public class HudScore {

```
    private int score;

    public HudScore(){
        score = 0;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void addPoints() {
        this.score +=50 ;
    }

}
```

In MainActivity:

public static final HudScore score = new HudScore();
score.addPoints();

Finally just compare with highscore you have set. If its above, save it in sharedPrefernce..

Comment: why do i put this in main activity? or where do i put this public static final HudScore score = new HudScore(); score.addPoints();